# How to fix php query in web application search bar and display results

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a search box in the navigation bar of my web application that appears on every web page. I have a query that is supposed to pull results from my database based on the text the user enters in the search box but at the moment it doesn't show any results.

My web application is essentially a post it board for events so I want a user to be able to search for an event and then have that event displayed in either a table or to take it to the page of the event itself whichever is easier. I am using Netbeans as my IDE and my database is a MariaDB in XAMPP. My web application is just locally hosted for now. I currently have a query that should search the database but I think the output of the query or the result is wrong. I'm not great at PHP but just need to do this as it is in every page of the web application.

The code of the search bar on every page:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for an event..">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Then the search.php file looks like this:

```
<?php


$search = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search');
$companyname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'companyname');
$eventname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventname');
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fyp";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "SELECT eventname FROM event WHERE eventname LIKE '%$search%'";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Result Found";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

At the moment, it just comes up saying "Connected successfullyError: SELECT eventname FROM event WHERE eventname LIKE '%Golf%'". I have an event called "SHARE Golf Classic" in the database so that's what I'm testing with currently. I would like to navigate to a page called Event.php and display the results in either a table or else fill labels or textboxes with the details of the event. The event table consists of eventid, eventname, eventtype, charityid, contactdetails, location and date.

Comment: remove the `%` symbol

Answer (score 0):

Determining errors of objects (Mysqli) can be difficult, that's why you should use `try-catch` approach instead. Your code could look like this:

```
<?php

$search = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search');
$companyname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'companyname');
$eventname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'eventname');
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fyp";

try {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT eventname FROM event WHERE eventname LIKE '%$search%'";
    if (($result = $conn->query($sql)) === true) {
        var_dump($result)
    }
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    var_dump($e)
} finally {
    $conn->close();
}
```

Please bear in mind that using parameters from `POST` request in the query like this can be dangerous. I would suggest looking into a different MySQL client for PHP ([PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

The code example above is also using `finally`, which was added in PHP 5.5, make sure your version is this or above (currently supported PHP versions are 7.2 and 7.3 - you should be always up to date).